# Plugman/cordova/phonegap using plugin by name

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, plugman

I have recently uploaded a new phonegap plugin https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1355 but I am not able to install it using

```
plugman install --platform android --project ./platforms/android --plugin com.zendrive.phonegap.sdk
```

or

```
plugman install --platform android --project ./ --plugin com.zendrive.phonegap.sdk
```

or

```
cordova plugin add com.zendrive.phonegap.sdk
```

I am getting 404 plugin not found error in all these cases.
Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/zendrive/zendrive-sdk-phonegap-plugin
```

100% works

Comment: I think its not possible to do a cloud build if I add a plugin that way. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578487/class-not-found-for-plugin-installed-by-plugman

Comment: And what is the use of uploading a plugin on build.phonegap.com if adding a plugin by name doesn't work.

Comment: I rather use URL instead package name

Comment: One more thing, I have to use plugman here. Is it possible to get it working with plugman. Cordova works just fine.

Comment: I'm not suggest to use it since it already obsolete. Use cordova instead plugman.