# Class not found for plugin installed by plugman

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, plugman

I have added a plugin to my cordova application using the following command

```
plugman install --platform android --project ./platforms/android --plugin https://github.com/zendrive/zendrive-sdk-phonegap-plugin.git
```

But, if I run

```
cordova run android --device
```

The config.xml file of android project automatically changes to remove the zendrive-sdk-phonegap-plugin and I receive "class not found" error when using the plugin api from code.

NOTE: 
The apk generated by phonegap cloud build has the same behaviour "class not found" and this plugin works just fine if I add plugin using

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/zendrive/zendrive-sdk-phonegap-plugin.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your class `src/android/com/zendrive/phonegap/ZendriveCordovaPlugin.java` not found that you declared inside `plugin.xml`.

Comment: That is present in plugin and it successfully gets added to the android project, but android config changes automatically while doing a cordova build.

Comment: It still java class not found. you need to recheck back.